# Sending mail reliably and doing it on a large scale

Tags: email, spam

my web application supposed to send email reminders in some point it will send large scale
but i do not what that the email servers that receive the email from my site will be marked and put to the black / spam list .
how can it be avoided ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Handle bounces religiously.  You will want to use a mailserver that supports something like [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) to make this easier.  Don't continue to send reminders to addresses that bounce consistently.
2. Allow people to unsubscribe.
3. Implement [DomainKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) for message signatures.  Particularly large email providers like Hotmail, Yahoo and Gmail put great stock in this.  The same goes for [SPF](http://openspf.org), although to a lesser degree (never use it to hard fail servers!)
4. Religiously check your mail server's status on major spam dns blacklists like those maintained by spamhaus.org and the like.  Try to get your server on popular whitelists.
5. Accept that, just sometimes, mail won't get through to a few customers.

Good luck.  Bulk email is a simple subject of mesmerizing complexity.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that effect this some of which include:

- Don't send to old / dormant addresses
- Manage bounce backs and don't mail them again
- Implement something like [domainkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)
- Use multiple IP addresses grouping mail of certain types together
- Set SPF records

Comment: i dont understand .. what is domainkeys . does my host need to implement this or i need to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not put things like "enlarge your penis" neither "viagra" nor cialis.

Seriously, I think there's little you can do to avoid this (else, all spammers could skip server protections).
You should warn your users that the email reminder could reach spam folder.